Do I need to create an AWS VPC interface endpoint for loading from Amazon S3 on Snowsight?
In the following Snowflake doc for setting up AWS PrivateLink, it is stated that "The Snowflake clients (e.g. SnowSQL, JDBC driver) require access to Amazon S3 to perform various runtime operations." May I know what are the "various runtime operations"? I couldn't get why SnowSQL or JDBC driver may require such an endpoint.
Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink#create-aws-vpc-interface-endpoints-for-amazon-s3
Actually I am planning to create an External Stage pointing to one of my AWS Account's S3 buckets on Snowsight's worksheet, and then load data from the S3 bucket to my Snowflake database. Moving on, I will also ONLY use Snowsight for all data loading and queries. After reading the doc above I am wondering whether there could be any missed consideration.
Thanks in advance!
I am trying to search by some keywords online but couldn't get much.

I might be misunderstanding your question, but the link you provided has all the details you'd need for why you might want to implement an S3 gateway endpoint.  What isn't clear in your question is whether you have implemented AWS Privatelink with Snowflake.  Loading data through an S3 bucket via external stage through scripts from Snowsight shouldn't require any special S3 gateway endpoints be configured.

Hi Mike, thank you for your response.
There are 2 doubts.


Why do SnowSQL or other clients may require access to Amazon S3 and hence a VPC interface endpoint is required. It is stated in the doc that it is required.


In the case of Snowsight, is it required to? I think Snowsight is also a kind of Snowflake clients.


